# How to get correct MD5 hash after saving canvas as .png in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, md5

I am trying to save image canvas to disk as .png in chrome extension with file name reflecting MD5 hash. For this I use something like this:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var image_data = atob(img.src.split(',')[1]);
var arraybuffer = new ArrayBuffer(image_data.length);
var view = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
for (var i=0; i<image_data.length; i++) {
   view[i] = image_data.charCodeAt(i);
}
var blob = new Blob([view], {type: 'image/png'});
var url = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);
var b = new FileReader;
b.readAsDataURL(blob);
b.onloadend = function () { 
   filename = SparkMD5.hash(b.result);
}
// ....some code
chrome.downloads.download ({ url, filename+'.png', saveAs: false });
```

The file is saved correctly, but MD5 hash that I get in code via SparkMD5 is different from the one I see in Windows after the file is saved. I cannot understand why. Experimented a bit with different approaches to saving (directly XMLHttpRequest, etc), but no luck yet. Probably I misunderstand some basic concept, as far as I am a bit of newbee to web programming.

I have also saved files via chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML with the use of FileReader and in that case MD5 are equal.
What is wrong and is there a way to get equal MD5 for filename and final file while saving .png from Chrome extension?

Comment: "different from the one I see in Windows after the file is saved" - What are you using to generate the MD hash in Windows? The algorithm used in SparkMD5 is probably different to that used to calculate the hash in Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I use Hash Tab in Windows (properties window for each of Windows files). Still  SparkMD5 seems to work identically to this when using it on mhtml, not png. So it seems not to be the reason for differences. My guess there shall be something related to canvas transformation to be further fed to SparkMD5 that leads to differences between file/blob.